# How to use a logical image as a mask for the original image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, mask, image-segmentation

I have an original image and only on some connected components I want to use the SIFT function. I was able to extract those regions and convert them to logical format as per the matlab help file:

> This section describes how to create binary masks to define ROIs.
>   However, any binary image can be used as a mask, provided that the
>   binary image is the same size as the image being filtered.

This is the original image

[image]

and here is the part I want, that I was able to extract in logical format:

[image]

Now I only want to apply the SIFT function on this single connected component of the original image.

I used the `createMask` function in the same format as explained in the help documentation:

```
img = imread(word.jpg);
h_im = imshow(img);
e = word_bw; %this is the image to be used as mask
BW = createMask(e,h_im);
```

I get the error: `Undefined function 'createMask' for input arguments of type 'logical'.`

How do I go about using my mask in a way that would allow me to apply functions to only that area in the original image?

Comment: Where's that magical function called `createMask`? It has to be in `path` as a `.m` file.

Comment: @Divakar Sorry? Are you asking where I picked up the code from? Well it was from this page: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/specifying-a-region-of-interest-roi.html

Comment: How about `BW = img.*word_bw`, assuming `img` to be a grayscale or binary image and `word_bw` as a binary array?

Comment: `createMask` is specifically for taking two handles (one is to an interactive ROI object), and outputting a logical mask. It doesn't do anything to the image. `word_bw;` is already a logical mask.

Comment: @nkjt Ah right I understand, so that is why I cant use it. If what I have is already a mask can you please suggest how I can use this to achieve what I want. Thank you

Comment: @Divakar img has to be grayscale and I cannot change it to logical, and the mask is already logical so I cant multiply the two together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
img_out = img;
img_out(~word_bw) = 0;
```

`img_out` would be the image with the mask from `word_bw` being applied.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your latest edit made it more clear. ``img_out = word_bw.*double(img)`` created an image which even though double appeared logical so I thought the original data was lost. So If I want to use functions like SIFT, do I have to use it with the ``unit8`` like ``SIFT(unit8(img_out))`` or is the ``unit8`` just for ``imshow`` and it SIFT will produce the same results even as is in double format? Thank you

Comment: @FarazKhan I am not too familiar with SIFT, but if it involves Image Processing, it mostly would expect `uint8` format input and thus, try with `uint8(255*word_bw)`. That would be `img_out_uint8` from the updated codes.

Comment: @FarazKhan Sorry I had to make major changes in the code. Could you check if the image shown in the solution is what you wanted?